# How to make app wait and then start activity or go back?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want my activity to show a screen for 3 seconds, then go back to previous screen. But when i use

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_layout);
        TextView tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)
        Thread.sleep(3000);
            Intent i = new Intent(this,myActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

But unfortunately, this does not work. This doesent show the activity waits 3 seconds and goes back. However, i want it to show its contents before going back. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove this   `Thread.sleep(3000);` which block the ui thread. You should never block the ui thred. You can use a Handler postDelayed with a delay and then startActivtiy.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
  public void run(){
   // do something
 }
 }, 3000);
```

To go back to previous Activity you can call `finish()`.

Also if you need to go back to the previous activity for 3 seconds why do you need

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,myActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Calling `finish()` will do the job

Comment: Here is the right answer after adding the code part ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the recommended way to do this.
Using `Thread.sleep` you're blocking the main UI thread for 3000 milliseconds. This means that nothing in the activity will work until 3 seconds are passed.

Instead, you could do this:
edited: now it works well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_layout);
    TextView tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Got this error: Android java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Comment: @user3316779 sorry! Checked, fixed and runned now it works fine.