# OnDestroy method doesnt work if I use a async task

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using destroy method inside my Activity, but if use await then my method doesn't work.

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Destroyed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}

protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.StartingImage);

    ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
    imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.StartingImage);

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    StartActivity(typeof(LoginMain));
    Finish();
    FinishAffinity();
}
```

I just need to preview an image for 5 seconds. But as I can imagine it doesn't finish my activity. Cause on destroy doesn't work.

Comment: onDestroy() is not supposed to work all the time. Use onPause() instead. But honestly, I have no idea what you're trying to do. Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Actually my basic question is: Does my activity destroyed? Cause i have an image inside imageview and i dont want my application keep it in stack

Comment: The answer is a "No". An activity won't necessarily get destroyed, even if you call finish on it. It really depends on the hardware of your device and what it decides to do. Sometimes, it will call onDestroy() if it needs to. And if it doesn't need to, it won't. That's why you should never rely on onDestroy()

Comment: But i need to destroy cause image is really big and i dont want to keep it in stack. Probably i will have memory heap problem.Should i retun on main ui thread after that?

Comment: use onPause() I know this doesn't make sense to you. The language of those callbacks doesn't make sense. Read the documentation. The documentation will agree with what I'm saying.

Comment: Are you just "trying" to display a "splash screen" before going to your login activity?

Comment: Thank you for answers. Then, should i use Finish onPause event?

Comment: Or if will use finishAffinity in next activity will it destroy previous one?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, by `An activity won't necessarily get destroyed, even if you call finish on it`, that means that even though the `OnDestroyed` called, the Activity is still alive? Could you please show me some documents about this? Cause I understand it from the document is that the Activity will be destoryed when the `OnDestory` called.

Comment: Hi, @testsc, if you can use `hanlder` achieve your goal. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430839/how-to-make-app-wait-and-then-start-activity-or-go-back)

Comment: @testsc, your code works well, and I haven't seen `async` in your `OnDestory`.

Comment: Yes, the Activity should get destroyed if you call onDestroy(), but only eventually. Unfortunately, the documentation isn't being super clear on this point, but the quote below from the linked documentation only alludes to what I am saying.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy%28%29 "Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!" I'm sorry I can't provide a better source. But most of the answers on StackOverflow agree with my opinion as well, even if the documentation isn't being super clear on this.